# PyMongo(3.6.1) - db.collection.aggregate(pipeline) NOT WORKING

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo, pipeline

I'm having trouble with PyMongo, I have been googling for hours, but found no solution.

I'm working with some Python Scripts just to practice with MongoDb, which is running on my local machine. I have populated my mongoDb instance with one database "moviesDB", which contains 3 different collections:

1.**Movies collection**, here is an example of a document from this coll:

```
{'_id': 1,
 'title': 'Toy Story (1995)',
 'genres': ['Adventure', 'Animation', 'Children', 'Comedy', 'Fantasy'], 
 'averageRating': 3.87,
 'numberOfRatings': 247, 
 'tags': [
            {'_id': ObjectId('5b04970b87977f1fec0fb6e9'), 
             'userId': 501, 
             'tag': 'Pixar',
             'timestamp': 1292956344}
          ]
 }
```

2.**Ratings collection**, which looks like this:

```
    {    '_id':ObjectId('5b04970c87977f1fec0fb923'), 
         'userId': 1, 
         'movieId': 31, 
         'rating': 2.5, 
         'timestamp': 1260759144}
```

3.Tags collection, that I won't use here, so it's not important.

Now, what I'm trying to do is: given a user (in this example, user 1), find all the genres of movies that he rated and per each genre list all the movieIds regarding that genre.
Here's my code:

```
"""
This query basically retrieves  movieIds, 
so from the result list of several documents like this:
{
    ObjectId('5b04970c87977f1fec0fb923'),
    'userId': 1, 
    'movieId': 31,
    'rating': 2.5,
    'timestamp': 1260759144},
 retrieves only an array of integers, where each number represent a movie 
 that the user 1 rated."""

movies_rated_by_user = list(db.ratings.distinct(movieId, {userId: 1}))

pipeline = [
    {"$match": {"_id ": {"$in": movies_rated_by_user}}},
    {"$unwind": "$genres"},
    {"$group": {"_id": "$genres", "movies": {"$addToSet": "$_id"}}}]

try:
    """HERE IS THE PROBLEM, SINCE db.movies.aggregate() RETURNS NOTHING!
   so the cursor is empty."""
    cursor = db.movies.aggregate(pipeline, cursor={})
except OperationFailure:
    print("Something went Wrong", file=open("operations_log.txt", "a"))
    print(OperationFailure.details, file=open("operations_log.txt", "a"))
    sys.exit(1)


aggregate_genre = []
for c in cursor:
    aggregate_genre.append(c)

print(aggregate_genre)
```

The point is that the aggregate function on the movies collection retrieves NOTHING, whereas it really should, since I tried this query on the MongoShell and it worked just fine. Here's how the mongoDB shell-query looks like:

```
db.movies.aggregate(
[
    {$match:{_id : {$in: ids}}},
    {$unwind : "$genres"},
    {$group :
        {
            _id : "$genres",
            movies: { $addToSet : "$_id" }}}
]
```

);

Where the 'ids' variables is defined like this, just like the movies_rated_by_user variable in the code:

```
ids= db.ratings.distinct("movieId", {userId : 1});
```

The result from the aggregate method looks like this (this is what the aggregate_genre variable in the code, should contain):

```
{ "_id" : "Western", "movies" : [ 3671 ] }
{ "_id" : "Crime", "movies" : [ 1953, 1405 ] }
{ "_id" : "Fantasy", "movies" : [ 2968, 2294, 2193, 1339 ] }
{ "_id" : "Comedy", "movies" : [ 3671, 2294, 2968, 2150, 1405 ] }
{ "_id" : "Sci-Fi", "movies" : [ 2455, 2968, 1129, 1371, 2105 ] }
{ "_id" : "Adventure", "movies" : [ 2193, 2150, 1405, 1287, 2105, 2294, 
    2968, 1371, 1129 ] }
```

Now the problem is the aggregate method, is there any error with the pipeline string??

PLEASE HELP!!
Thank you

Comment: Slow down. You keep editing and you're already asking too much. Simply start debugging the problem. You are sending a list of values into `$match`, what are they? Which documents should they match? Just show us the list of values and the things you expect them to match. That's your first stop on "what is wrong" when you get no results.

Comment: Sorry for editing too much, I was trying to fix some issues.

Comment: Anyways, movies_rated_by_user  contains all the ratings records where the user number 1 appears as the userId, that is the user who made the rating. I used the 'distinct method'  so that It would return only the moviesId of the movies the user rated, and match from the movies collection only those movies that the user rated. Essentially is an array of integers, representing movieIds.

Comment: The only edit you really need to concern yourself with is providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Which means show your inputs for any variables and show example documents from which you expect to reasonably return a desired result. If you give people something they can actually reproduce, it makes spotting problems and advising on what to do so much more simple than trawling through a magnum opus of a question. A good question need not be a life story, and simply needs to provide the right details in order to solve it.

Comment: Better now? I reduced the code only where to problem is.

Comment: Hi @GiorgiaTandoi. First, this query `movies_rated_by_user = list(db.ratings.distinct(movieId, {userId: 1}))` doesn't look right. It should be `movies_rated_by_user = list(db.ratings.distinct('movieId', {'userId': 1}))` or something where the key is an instance of basestring and the filter is a python dictionary. Also, the second argument to aggregrate method of the collection is for when you want to return a CommandCursor. What you want is a query cursor, so it's okay to lose the second cursor argument passed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to cast the cursor to a list before iterating through it. Hope this helps.

```
cursor = list(db.movies.aggregate(pipeline, cursor={}))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I already tried that, still doesn't work. I think that the problem is in how pymongo elaborates the query, because the cursor is empty, even if I cast it to a list, it just doesn't find nothing that matches the aggregate method.

Comment: Why do you use a second argument for the aggregate function, what does it do?